# Using NOT EXISTS clause in sqlalchemy ORM query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to convert the following raw sql query into a sqlalchemy ORM query :

```
SELECT * FROM kwviolations AS kwviol WHERE kwviol.proj_id=1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
kwmethodmetrics AS kwmetrics WHERE kwmetrics.kw_id=kwviol.kw_id AND kwmetrics.checkpoint_id=5);
```

I tried the following ORM query but didn't succeed:

```
self.session.query(KWViolations).filter(KWViolations.proj_id==project.id).\
filter(and_(~KWViolations.kw_id.any(KWMethodMetrics.kw_id==KWViolations.kw_id),KWMethodMetrics.checkpoint_id==checkpoint.id))
```

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`kw_id` here seems to be a scalar column value, so you can't call `any()` on that - `any()` is only available from a [relationship()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) bound attribute.  Since I don't see one of those here you can call the [exists()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html?highlight=exists#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists) directly:

```
from sqlalchemy import exists

session.query(KWViolations).filter(KWViolations.proj_id == project.id).\
    filter(
        ~exists().where(
                and_(
                    KWMethodMetrics.kw_id == KWViolations.kw_id,
                    KWMethodMetrics.checkpoint_id == checkpoint.id
                )
        )
    )
```